# Wrong sign in the energy method on Minkowski space

Tags: calculus, physics, stokes-theorem, divergence-operator, semi-riemannian-geometry

Given any vector field $X$ in Minkowski space, we can use Stokes' theorem to derive
$$
\int_{t_0}^{t_1}\text{div} X \text d V_g =\int_{\{t=t_0\}} g(X,\partial_t)-\int_{\{t=t_1\}} g(X,\partial_t),
$$
where the first integral refers to integration over the slab between the two planes of constant time at $t_0$ and $t=1$. I have tripled check this calculation and convinced myself that the RHS is indeed correct; we subtract the flow through the bottom slice from the flow through the top slice. As a sanity check, if $X=T:=\partial_t$, then the flow through a section of the bottom plane is negative, as intuition would dictate, although if this is wrong, please let me know.

My problem comes when I plug in an energy current $X^a = Q^a{}_{b} T^b$ where $Q$ is the stress-energy tensor for some function $u$:
$$
Q_{ab}=\nabla_a u\nabla_b u-\frac 12 g_{ab}\nabla^c u\nabla_c u.
$$
In this case, say in spherical coordinates, I have
$$
X =\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac 12 |\partial u|^2
\\
u_t u_r
\\
\frac 1{r^2}u_t u_\theta
\\
\frac 1{r^2\sin^2 \theta}u_t u_\varphi
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Using the coordinate formula for the divergence I am able to verify that $\text{div} X = u_t \square u = u_t(\Delta u - u_{tt})$, but $Q(X,\partial_t)=\frac 12 |\partial u|^2$, so that the RHS of
$$
2\int_{t_0}^{t_1}u_t\square u \text d V_g =\int_{\{t=t_0\}}|\partial u|^2 -\int_{\{t=t_1\}} |\partial u|^2,
$$
has the opposite sign from the correct energy estimate. After going through some textbooks I am pretty sure the formula for the divergence theorem is correct, so I imagine the mistake must be somewhere in the calculations for the energy current $X$. Since I get the correct LHS, I think the expression for $X$ is correct, so maybe I am missing some detail with the inner product, but I do not see how. Where am I making a mistake?

EDIT:
I am just now realizing that I do obtain the correct energy identity because my wave operator is the negative of the conventional one $u_{tt} - \Delta u$. However, I have seen in several notes (e.g. [these ones](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/wangq1/Lecture_notes/nonlinear_wave_9.pdf) on slide 78) that the regular energy identity (i.e. the one for the conventional wave operator) holds even when they have explicitly defined
$$
\square u = g^{\mu \nu} \nabla_\mu \nabla_\nu u
$$
do the authors actually mean $\square u= - g^{\mu \nu} \nabla_\mu \nabla_\nu u$?

Comment: This question - particularly after the edit - would be far better asked in the Physics forum, as it relies heavily on the physical interpretation of these formulas, not just the mathematics itself.